# How can I scrape code inside div with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am having problems scraping code inside div not between them, with BeautifulSoup and python. Below I wrote a html code what I want to **scrape** (data-friendscount ,  data-followerscount Values)

```
<div data-profileuserid="285904056" data-friendscount="100" data-followerscount="7102" data-followingscount="25" data-arefriends="false" class="hidden ng-isolate-scope"></div>
```

Comment: Have you seen https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes ? What did you try to get the value?

Comment: yes I need values

Comment: Could you share some more code, what you tried? To me, the docs are quite conclusive on what to do.
Perhaps there's a small typo or so. How do you process above HTML?

Comment: I can't share my code cause it isn't working , I have no idea how to scrap data in div.
I can give you link https://www.roblox.com/users/285904056/profile -- Trying to get followers number

Comment: `soup = BeautifulSoup(html_here)` then `tag = soup.div` an `tag.get(attribute_here)` as starter (replace the `_here` parts).

Comment: @justas1205 It's actually encouraged to share your non-working code with us, that's the best way for you to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
toc = requests.get(f'roblox.com/users/75790059/profile')
soup = BeautifulSoup(toc.content, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="hidden ng-isolate-scope")
for div in divs:
    print(div.attrs.get('data-profileuserid', None))
    print(div.attrs.get('data-friendscount', None))
    print(div.attrs.get('data-followerscount', None))
    print(div.attrs.get('data-followingscount', None))
    print(div.attrs.get('data-arefriends', None))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am unable to find that div with link maybe you could help me find ? Here is the photo for what I am looking https://imgur.com/nhUrDwY in https://www.roblox.com/users/285904056/profile

Comment: See my edit. I added the soup.find_all to search for all divs with the class = 'hidden ng-isolate-scope'. Then you can loop over all divs matching that class name

Comment: I added this but brings me nothing 

`toc = requests.get(f'https://www.roblox.com/users/75790059/profile').text
soup = BeautifulSou(toc, 'html.parser')

Comment: See edit. You should use toc.content and remove the .text from the get function

Comment: Strange , still nothing but if I search for all divs I get them

Comment: Please accept the answer as it answered what you asked initially. I cannot access your site from my network to see what is wrong with the request